# Laravel serve without affecting the other apps

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, directory, command-line-interface

I have installed Laravel 5 and I know there's no way to run
'php artisan serve' anymore.

Laravel project is in a subfolder: www.site.com/laravelProject.

Can I run this command (in my laravel project folder) from CLI:

```
php -S localhost/project:8000 -t public/
```

without affecting the other folders from live (from localhost) ?

I mean, this command will still let the other folders running and being accessed with their url?

Will still the other folders work?

Thx :)

## Edit:

'php artisan serve' actually works.

But there's a problem:

```
user@server# php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

I actually have it on remote server, not locally. How can I fix it?

Comment: `php artisan serve` still works. what makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: You can make a virtual host nstead.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here: `without affecting the other folders from live (from localhost) ?`...

Comment: I mean folders which aren't in localhost/project folder. Like localhost/anything-else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the answer you get when running `php artisan serve`, this command only starts a **development** server.

For production, you have to setup a Virtual Host pointing to your Laravel application.

An example Virtual Host for Apache would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/myName/Projects/laravel/public"
    ServerName myLaravel.dev
    <Directory "/Users/myName/Projects/laravel/public">
            AllowOverride All
            Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```